# Dart Parse Server creating an index for full text search

Tags: dart, parse-platform, parse-server, back4app

I'm trying to use [dart parse server](https://pub.dev/packages/parse_server_sdk) in order to do a [full-text search](https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#queries-on-string-values) as explained here.
So far as I understand, I have the falling 2 options if I want to do that:

- whereContainsWholeWord
- whereContains

In the case of the first one, I will search the whole database for that specific word, and for the second one, I will search the database for some partial word.

This is exactly what I need, but because the second search is going to utilize regex, this is going to be slow.

Is there any way to create an index for full-text search via the dart parse server, and afterward use some query on that index? Or this feature is not implemented yet, because I could not find anything in this regard in the document

Comment: What do you think of using cloud code functions for that?
Then, you only need to call the cloud code function with the parameters you need.

In Javascript (which is the SDK that cloud code uses), you can do something like this: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#full-text-search

Comment: That's now exactly what I want because everything is related to the word search, I would like something like an autocomplete functionality, but parse server did not provide anything like that